# Is it possible to use `std::set_intersection` to check if two sets have any element in common?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, c++17

[`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) allows me to retrieve all elements in common between two `std::set` instances by outputting elements to an *output iterator*. In my particular situation, I am only interested in **checking whether or not two sets have any element in common**.

My current solution is using [`boost::function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) to set a `bool` variable as follows:

```
bool b{false};
set_intersection(begin(s0), end(s0),
                 begin(s1), end(s1),
                 make_function_output_iterator([&](const auto&){ b = true; }));
return b;
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not return early if a match is found: the sets have to be traversed entirely *(i.e. no early return / short-circuiting)*.

**Is it possible to use `set_intersection` with early return?** The only solution I can think of is throwing an exception from the `function_output_iterator` *function object*, which is a terrible idea.

If not, is there anything else in the Standard Library that can help me, or am I forced to reimplement `set_intersection`? Bonus question: how would `set_intersection`'s interface look like if it allowed early termination *(i.e. what is the "most general" interface a Standard Library algorithm could have)*?

Comment: Being super pedantic: It's not restricted to `std::set`, only a sorted range.

Comment: Pedantic remark: I never said that it's restricted to `std::set`.

Comment: I think a for loop that runs `lower_bound` repeatedly is not too bad. I don't think we can properly make `set_intersection` do as you wish.

Comment: Do you want the same algorithmic complexity?  `std::find_first_of` short circuits but is `O(N*M)`.  `std::any_of` with a predicate that search the other set in a `log(M)` way gives you `O(Nlog(M))` with short circuiting.

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes, I would like the same (or better) complexity guarantees as `set_intersection`.

Comment: @AndyG: ``std::set::find`` is sufficient here. Also, it should be noted that ``std::lower_bound`` has linear time complexity for ``std::set`` iterators (``std::set::lower_bound`` does not have this limitation). Anyway, this approach is very efficient if the sets' size differs much, i.e. iterate over the smaller set and use ``find`` on the larger set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, being “forced” to reimplement `std::set_intersection` isn’t such a bad thing. <g> It’s only about five lines of code:

```
template <class I1, class I2>
bool have_common_element(I1 first1, I1 last1, I2 first2, I2 last2) {
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2)
            ++first1;
        else if (*first2 < *first1)
            ++first2;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Okay, a bit more than 5 lines. But painless.

Answer (score 3):

This simple algorithm should do it:

#### Features:

- complexity: At most K=max(N, M) iterations where N is distance(first1, last1), and M is distance(first2, last2)
- short circuits
- works with any sorted range
- predicate can be replaced

```
#include <set>
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

template<class I1, class I2, class Comp = std::less<> >
bool has_element_in_common(I1 first1, I1 last1, I2 first2, I2 last2, Comp&& comp = Comp())
{
    while (first1 != last1 and first2 != last2)
    {
        if (comp(*first1, *first2))
        {
            ++first1;
        }
        else if (comp(*first2, *first1))
        {
            ++first2;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    auto s1 = std::set<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    auto s2 = std::set<int> { 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 };

    assert(has_element_in_common(begin(s1), end(s1), begin(s2), end(s2)));

    auto s3 = std::set<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

    assert(!has_element_in_common(begin(s1), end(s1), 
                                  begin(s3), end(s3)));

}
```

It'll need a little work if you want to optimise it to skip duplicates in multisets.

Comment: To be even more generic `first` and `last` might be different types.

Comment: @Jarod42 Agree. I was being a little lazy. Ideally the algorithm needs to know the container type since it can optimise the steps on multisets by using the `equal_range()` member.

Comment: What does "max O(N)" mean in this context?

Comment: @AndyG because the algo can short-circuit, the complexity is O(N) only in the worst case of there being no match.

Comment: To nitpick the common O(...) (ab)use; generally we'd still say the complexity is just O(N), as we're not counting the exact number of basic operations(/iterations, here) with Big-O notation, but are studying the magnitude of these asymptotically (on e.g. average/worst case). For a single run we might short-circuit at ~0.1 * N iterations, or e.g. ~0.5 * N on average over a large set of test sets, but the asymptotic (time-)complexity of the algorithm is none the less O(N). (If we, on the other hand, are interested in actual num. of iterations, _"At most `K=max(N, M)` iterations"_ would suffice).

Comment: @dfri nicely put. Updated. But I say it's `K=min(N, M)` since we'd do zero iterations if `N` or `M` was zero.

Comment: @AndyG w.r.t. asymptotic complexity (using iteration as basic operation), it is `O(K)`, where `K=max(N, M)`. W.r.t. number of actual iterations, `N+M` should indeed be an _upper_ bound. Or, exactly, `(N-1) + (M-1) - 1 = N + M - 1`; `N-1` in case `first1` needs to be fully incremented to its final element (prior to `last1`) and the same holds for `first2` (`M-1` increments), and then a final single increment for one of the iterators to terminate the predicate (e.g. `{1, 2, 8}` and `{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` hits worst case). However this is still cheap as compared e.g. the sorting upon set construction.

Comment: @dfri ah yes, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can throw a exception ,Although the exception  overhead is large....and according to the programming style, you shouldn't use it like this:

```
bool find=false;
try{
set_intersection(begin(s0), end(s0),
                 begin(s1), end(s1),
                 make_function_output_iterator([&](const auto&){throw true;}));
}catch{
   find= true;
}
```